# What are expl3 quarks? When, where, why and how should I use them?

Tags: programming, latex3, expl3

I feel particularly bombarded by sub-atomic particles right now (and it's mostly Will's fault `:)`). First, in Will's answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5116/making-switch-case-with-etoolboxs-ifdefequal) today, he referred to `expl3`'s `\prg_case_str:nnn` command.  Digging into the package, I noticed the command involves an interestingly named macro called `\quark_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:nn`.  All I can gather from the `expl3` documentation about things with the word (particle`;)`) `quark` in their name is that:

> **l3quark** A ‘quark’ is a command that is defined to expand to itself! Therefore they
>   must never be expanded as this will generate infinite recursion; they do however
>   have many uses, e.g. as special markers and delimiters within code.

Hmmm.

Coincidentally, Will and Kevin's new `hardwrap` package was released on CTAN today (many congrats guys!).  Digging into the documented code, I notice:

> `\hw@scanstop`
>
> This is a ‘quark’ from expl3 designed to delimit scanning; it will never be
>   executed, else an infinite loop results.
>
> `\protected\def\hw@scanstop{\hw@scanstop}`

Reading the remainder of `hardwrap`'s code, yes, `\hw@scanstop` is used in exactly the way described in the definition of **l3quark**, above.

Still, I'm perplexed. What's so special about self-referencing tokens as opposed to any other token assigned a special-purpose name, i.e., any other vanilla signifier, whether a command sequence or not? Are they self-referencing only for error-catching purposes?

If LaTeX quarks do have interesting properties beyond just being specially defined and used signifiers, where, when, how and why should I best employ them?

Are they *really* `expl3` specific, or is it more a convention that has been adopted into the LaTeX3 programming patterns set?

Finally, out of interest (in the spirit of Yiannis's [recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/lisp-relics-in-latexe-logo) about Lisp `car` and `cdr` "relics" in TeX's lexicon), what's the story about how the word `quark` found its way into LaTeX3 vocabulary? (Please tell me that `LaTeX3` quarks aren't envisioned to possess color, flavor, etc. properties!)

Comment: In `hardwarp` I'm afraid Will is not quite right: as he's `\protected` the definition this is not a quark. I know that because I tried something similar and found it does not work. As Hendrik explains, the key is `\ifx` testing, and there `\protected` status is important. If you store a quark inside a variable, then the `\ifx` will only be true if the quark is not protected (variables are not protected).

Comment: @Joseph Wright, thanks for the great info and your comment below, but the +1 is for writing `hardwarp` apropos the question's quantum theme! `:)`

Comment: @JosephW yes, you're right these aren't really quarks—at one stage they weren't `\protected` but the code documentation stuck. Oh well `:)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So many questions. I'm only going to address "What's so special about self-referencing tokens?", and I'm giving a plain TeX answer. As I learned from TH (at the end of a rather lengthy comment-discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3682/how-do-i-lower-the-widetilde-accent-i-e-move-it-closer-to-the-variable/3725#3725)), they can be useful for `\ifx` tests. If I know that `#1` is one token, and I do the test

```
\ifx#1\my@test@token
```

to find out if `#1` is `\my@test@token`, then it is good to have the definition

```
\def\my@test@token{\my@test@token}
```

For `\ifx`, two control sequences are the same if they have the same definition (including every detail such as parameters and other stuff), but they won't be expanded for the comparison. (That shouldn't happen as you explained above.) For an example see TH's very nice answer that I linked to above.

Be careful: The `\ifx` test also works if `\my@test@token` is undefined, but then it turns out true whenever `#1` is an undefined control sequence.

Comment: This is a key reason for the definition as-is. It makes it possible to do fast tests for a variable containing only a quark, which means that the quark can then be used as a marker of 'no value' or such like. The key point here is performance on single-token tests: this is necessary as these tests come up an awful lot.

Comment: Great explanation, Hendrik. So, summing up, LaTeX3 quarks are basically conventional sentinels which, for efficiency reasons, to guarantee they will never collide with or match any token except themselves (including undefined), and maybe to make any errors with using them pretty obvious (stack overflow), they're defined first-order as themselves. Reading between the lines, LaTeX3 quarks are conventionally (always?) used as sentinals, but rather than calling them 'sentinels', LaTeX3 (but not necessarily TeX/LaTeX2) idiom names them 'quarks' (à la TeX's  'whatsits' `:))` ).

Comment: @GeoffreyJ Right, and I have no idea where the name ‘quark’ came from. (I like the name a lot, though.) One other advantage of them is that you can expand a quark once and end up with the same thing, which might also be occasionally useful.

Comment: @Will: From that viewpoint, a quark is like a quine, and those two words are rather similar.

Comment: @GeoffreyJones The main drawback of quarks is that because TeX optimizes tail calls, expanding a quark leads to an infinite loop rather than a stack overflow.  Still something detectable (TeX hangs), but not nearly as nice, since it takes time to realize.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch (not really related but you're LaTeX maintainer) Thinking about it, wouldn't `[optional \protected] \def \quark \quark {}` have the same property and eliminate that error? (actually it would probably the *faster* if I recalled correctly... because internally TeX macro definition is stored like [(refcount) (parameter text) [imaginary →] (replacement text)] so you get to skip comparing the `→` first?)

Comment: TBH I don't like quarks, but one reason to have defined them the way they are is that you might have stored the token in a tl variable (a macro without parameters) and then `\l_your_tl` and the quark will compare equal.  So you don't need to worry whether you've just grabbed the quark as an argument, or stored into a token list.  I don't think this comes up that often in modern code, but it is probably too entrenched to change it at this late point.