# What's the benefit of defining a macro that expands to itself?

Tags: macros, pgffor

While was looking at the source code for `pgffor`, I noticed the macro `\pgffor@stop` is defined as

```
\def\pgffor@stop{\pgffor@stop}
```

I think the macro is used to stop argument parsing. If that's the case, what is the benefit of defining it recursively? Won't that cause an infinite loop if it is ever (accidentally) expanded? Why isn't it defined as `{}` or maybe even `\relax`?

Comment: Yes, it would cause an infinite loop if it is expanded but then something went wrong which it shouldn't have. `\pgffor@stop` is only used to detect something which usually will also gobble it up and not actually expand it. You can also use a macro that is never defined but that also `\ifx`-equals against other undefined macros (whch shouldn't be around but could be). In addition to what Joseph wrote, it also is almost impossible for a user to accidently trigger it.

Comment: With `\def\pgffor@stop{}` this will break very easily: `\foreach \x in {1,2,,4}{``\x'' }`.

Comment: Near duplicate of [programming - What are expl3 quarks? When, where, why and how should I use them? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5220/what-are-expl3-quarks-when-where-why-and-how-should-i-use-them?rq=1) except for the name

Comment: In argument parsing, `\def\foo#1\bar{#1}` will pull text until it reaches `\bar` so you want to make sure `\bar` is never actually used inside #1.  If `\bar` is a quartk, it can't be used as text without crashing, only as a delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro is `\ifx` equal to itself even if stored inside another macro

```latex
\def\some@store{\pgffor@stop}
\ifx\some@store\pgffor@stop
 % TRUE
\fi
```

This makes it useful for fast tests that are used with macros-as-variables.

Note that if you need to be sure of a unique ID, you can't use `\relax` or `{}`, at least if you are testing using `\ifx`. (With a modern TeX system you can do an expandable *string* test, so you can check the name of the token.)

```latex
\def\pgffor@stop@bad{}
\def\foo#1{\ifx#1\pgffor@stop@bad ...}
\foo\@empty % Oops
```