# Implementing switch cases

Tags: conditionals

I'd like to have command built around a `switch-case` environment in LaTeX, much like the example below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\dothis}[1]{%
\IfStrEqCase{#1}{{a}{so you typed a}
    {b}{now this is b}
    {c}{you want me to do c?}}
    [nada]
}

\begin{document}

\dothis{a}

\dothis{b}

\dothis{c}

\dothis{e}

\end{document}
```

My problem with it is that it requires the `xstring` package. Is there any other way to do this? Preferably without loading additional packages and avoiding disgraceful thickets of `\if-\else-\fi` statements?

Comment: Are we allowed to use `\pdfstrcmp`?

Comment: @JosephWright: Any ideas are welcome. :)

Comment: After various troubles with alternatives, I ended up using the [`\str_case:nnF` construct](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5210/15665) that expl3 makes available through e.g. `\usepackage{xparse}`. I was initially put off by the unusual characters in the macro name, but that was a mistake — it just has to be surrounded by `\ExplSyntaxOn`, `\ExplSyntaxOff` to make that syntax valid.

Comment: Just a note that `\str_case:nnF` is documented in [interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The question asks to avoid packages, so while this is the method used by `expl3` in `\str_case:nnF` I have recoded it with minimal support. The only package I've used is `pdftexcmds`, which is needed as the `\pdfstrcmp` primitive from pdfTeX is called `\strcmp`  by XeTeX and has to be implemented in Lua for LuaTeX. This is easy enough to do without the package, but obscures the method: ask a separate question if required!

The general idea here is to set up a comparison loop in which the test is done expandably by `\pdfstrcmp`. The test string is passed every time, with the 'true' string inserted if there is a match by the 'tidy up' code. If there is no match at all then the 'else' code is inserted. The `\romannumeral` business means that it always requires exactly two expansions to do the work here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\dothis}[1]{%
  \stringcases
    {#1}%
    {%
      {a}{so you typed a}%
      {b}{now this is b}%
      {c}{you want me to do c?}%
    }%
    {[nada]}%
}
\newcommand{\stringcases}[3]{%
  \romannumeral
    \str@case{#1}#2{#1}{#3}\q@stop
}
\newcommand{\str@case}[3]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{\unexpanded{#2}}=\z@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
    {\str@case@end{#3}}
    {\str@case{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\str@case@end}{}
\long\def\str@case@end#1#2\q@stop{\z@#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\dothis{a}

\dothis{b}

\dothis{c}

\dothis{e}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure which other methods you are referring to.  I don't see how the loop could be avoided?  Or is the `\pdfstrcmp` primitive particularly slow?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I was thinking in particular of a non-expandable version where you you store in detokenized in a macro and use a series of baked-in `\ifx` tests. `\ifx` is fast, and `\pdfstrcmp` is slower, but you then have the nested `\if` ... `\fi` business we were asked to avoid.

Comment: I benchmarked, and `\ifx` seemed just as slow as `\pdfstrcmp`, as long as the tokens' string representations are not too long. `\ifx` is only very fast for comparisons between macros let to each other (since TeX then only has to compare one number).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch OK, I'll edit that out then :-)

Answer (score 30):

Though it's most likely too late for the OP, I just worked out my own switch and thought I'd share it here for future readers. My solution uses solely the package `xifthen` (`ifthen` suffices too, but I already had `xifthen` installed...).

```
% Switch implementation
\usepackage{xifthen}
\newcommand{\ifequals}[3]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{#2}}{#3}{}}
\newcommand{\case}[2]{#1 #2} % Dummy, so \renewcommand has something to overwrite...
\newenvironment{switch}[1]{\renewcommand{\case}{\ifequals{#1}}}{}

% Example: Pick color by ID
\newcommand{\incolor}[2]{
    \begin{switch}{#1}
        \case{1}{\color{red}}
        \case{2}{\color{blue}}
        \case{3}{\color{green}}
        \case{4}{\color{black}}
        #2
    \end{switch}
}
```

This code compiles perfectly fine in my TeXMaker (ofc. you'll need the color-package for this example, but it's not part of the switch). The example colors a given input in a color defined by an ID I chose (Usage: `\incolor{ID}{Content}`). I used it for shorthand notations of lots of things (e.g. `\lp1`, `\lp2`, ... for parentheses in different colors using `\newcommand{\lp}[1]{\incolor{#1}{\langle}}`). Feel free to experiment ;)

I could imagine this to be expanded to a solution using only built-in control structures, but I've been too lazy for now to do so, yet `\ifx` and `\else` should do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no easy way to provide a default base case if nothing matches, with this approach.

Comment: You can delete the line `\newcommand{\case}[2]{#1 #2}` and simply use `\newcommand` when defining the `switch` environment.

Comment: Ah, I see why `\renewcommand` is better than `\newcommand`. If you want to use nested switch environments, then using `\newcommand` will cause an error in the inner switch environment because the `\case` command will already be defined in the outer environment.

Answer (score 11):

There is the built-in `\ifcase` which works like a switch-case that interpret numbers. Because of this, I translated the strings 'a', 'b', 'c' to numbers 0, 1, 2. Note that the first case is 0. It don't need packages and is very simple.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\dothis}[1]{%
\ifcase#1\relax so you typed a % Case 0.

\or now this is b % Case 1.

\or you want me to do c? % Case 2.

\else Default case.
\fi
}
\begin{document}
\dothis{0}

\dothis{1}

\dothis{2}

\dothis{3}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The following is from *catoptions* package. The following `\ifcasse` is `\cptifcasse` in *catoptions* package. I think Count Zero should simply load an existing package for his task.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\long\def\am@alltoendif#1\endif{\unexpanded{#1}}
\long\def\am@domatchcode#1#2\endif{\unexpanded{#1}}
\long\def\amifcond#1\fi{\csname @#1first\else second\fi oftwo\endcsname}
\long\def\amifstrcmp#1#2{%
  \amifcond\if0\pdf@strcmp{\detokenize{#1}}{\detokenize{#2}}\fi
}
\def\ifcasse#1#2{%
  \amifstrcmp{#1}\ifnone{%
    \am@alltoendif
  }{%
    \amifstrcmp{#1}\endif{}{%
      \amifstrcmp{#2}\ifnone{%
        \am@alltoendif
      }{%
        \amifstrcmp{#2}\endif{}{\am@ifcasse{#1}{#2}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\def\am@ifcasse#1#2#3{%
  \amifstrcmp{#3}\ifnone{%
    \am@alltoendif
  }{%
    \amifstrcmp{#3}\endif{}{%
      #1{#2}{#3}\am@domatchcode{\am@ifcasse@i{#1}{#2}}%
    }%
  }%
}
\def\am@ifcasse@i#1#2#3{\am@ifcasse{#1}{#2}}

% The user can also define his own logical test command and pass it as the first 
% argument of \ifcasse. For example, we define \ifnumtest:

\def\ifnumtest#1#2{\amifcond\ifnum#1#2\fi}

% We rewrite Count Zero's macro:
\newcommand*{\dothis}[1]{%
  \par
  \ifcasse\amifstrcmp{#1}%
    {a}{so you typed a}
    {b}{now this is b}
    {c}{you want me to do c?}
  \ifnone
    [no match]%
  \endif
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\dothis{a}
\dothis{b}
\dothis{c}
\dothis{e}

% Weird test that correctly gives \x as 'empty':
\edef\x{%
  \ifcasse\amifstrcmp{x}
  \endif
}
%\show\x

% Weird test that gives \x as 'no match':
\edef\x{%
  \ifcasse\amifstrcmp{x}
  \ifnone
    [no match]%
  \endif
}
\par``\x''.

% Number test:
\edef\x{%
  \ifcasse\ifnumtest{2}
    {=1}{equal to 2}
    {<3}{less than 3}
    {>4}{greater than 4}
  \ifnone
    no match%
  \endif
}
\par``\x''.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Defining a string comparison macro which works like `\pdfstrcmp` is probably not reasonable (there was some code for an expandable comparison in `expl3`, but it dropped spaces so does not count). I was only meaning that it's not too hard to test the engine version and pick the correct name for the functionality (or to define in Lua).

Comment: @JosephWright: You're right. I have seen one edge failure mode with the `\strcmp` command that I tried to create, but I don't have the time to fix it now. I have therefore edited my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution via macro definitions (a single test makes the choice):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\addcase[3]{\expandafter\def\csname\string#1@case@#2\endcsname{#3}}
\newcommand\makeswitch[2][]{%
  \newcommand#2[1]{%
    \ifcsname\string#2@case@##1\endcsname\csname\string#2@case@##1\endcsname\else#1\fi%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\makeswitch[nada]\dothis
\addcase\dothis{a}{so you typed a}
\addcase\dothis{b}{so you typed b}
\addcase\dothis{c}{you want me to do c?}

\begin{document}
\dothis{a}

\dothis{b}

\dothis{c}

\dothis{e}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was just looking to see if this type of approach was represented.  I find it the most excellent of approaches. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Based on the great answer by Thev and updated by MaxD I have implemented a `\default` command for switch. I used `ifthen` package:

```
\newboolean{default}
\newcommand{\case}{}
\newcommand{\default}{}

\newenvironment{switch}[1]{%
    \setboolean{default}{true}
    \renewcommand{\case}[2]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{##1}}{%
        \setboolean{default}{false}##2}{}}%
    \renewcommand{\default}[1]{\ifthenelse{\boolean{default}}{##1}{}}
}{}

Then implement it as such:

  \begin{switch}{\program}  
    \case{2}{\twodayprogram}  
    \case{4}{\fourdayprogram}  
    \default{\first\ \last\ missing program\pagebreak}  
  \end{switch}
```

*in case anyone is curious, this was a program for an off-season sports conditioning program and was being looped with `datatool`, the commands `\twodayprogram` and `\fourdayprogram` implement the program for a particular athlete*

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple extension to [Thev's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187710), adding support for a default case.

```
% Switch implementation
\usepackage{xifthen}
\newcommand{\ifequals}[4]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{#2}}{#3}{#4}}
\newcommand{\case}[2]{#1 #2} % Dummy, so \renewcommand has something to overwrite...
\newenvironment{switch}[1]{\renewcommand{\case}{\ifequals{#1}}}{}

% Example: Pick color by ID
\newcommand{\incolor}[2]{
    \begin{switch}{#1}
        \case{1}{\color{red}}{
        \case{2}{\color{blue}}{
        \case{3}{\color{green}}{
        \case{4}{\color{black}}{
        \color{cyan}
        }}}}
    \end{switch}
    #2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*Sorry for being late to the party. :-)*

*expl3/xparse/ltcmd bring along nice tools for case-forking. Since the 2020-10-01 release [expl3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3) and [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) (the latter re-branded as [ltcmd](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf#part.7) and deprived of things that are not considered good practice any more) are included in the LaTeX 2e-format. So nowadays you could use expl3/ltcmd "out of the box" without loading additional packages. But in 2012, when the question was asked, xparse/expl3 needed to be loaded as additional packages while the question requests things to be done without loading additional packages. Thus I assume that the focus of the question is on "old school code".*

---

You can easily avoid any `\if..\else..\fi`-thingie without loading whatsoever additional packages if you do things in terms of delimited arguments:

```latex
\makeatletter
\errorcontextlines=10000
%%=============================================================================
%% PARAPHERNALIA:
%% \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull,
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UD@GobbleToExclam{\long\def\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@abcFork{%
  \long\def\UD@abcFork#1!a!b!c!#2#3!!!!{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}%
}%
\newcommand\dothis[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
               \expandafter{\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!}{%
    \UD@abcFork
    !#1!b!c!{so you typed a}% <-this is \UD@abcFork's 2nd arg if #1 = a
    !a!#1!c!{now this is b}% <-this is \UD@abcFork's 2nd arg if #1 = b
    !a!b!#1!{you want me to do c?}% <-this is \UD@abcFork's 2nd arg if #1 = c
    !a!b!c!{[nada]}%  <-this is \UD@abcFork's 2nd arg if #1 neither a nor b nor c
    !!!!% <-this is the delimiter of \UD@abcFork's 3rd argument
  }{\UD@stopromannumeral[nada]}% <-This is done if #1 contains ! and thus could erroneously match the delimiter !a!b!c!
}%
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\dothis{a}

\dothis{b}

\dothis{c}

\dothis{e}

\dothis{!e!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you wish to combine cases, e.g. "You typed a or d", you can combine the above forking-technique with a routine for extracting the K-th argument from a list of undelimited arguments so that the number K is provided by the forking-mechanism:

```latex
\makeatletter
\errorcontextlines=10000
%%=============================================================================
%% PARAPHERNALIA:
%% \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond,
%% \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull,
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%%
%% Extract K-th inner undelimited argument:
%%
%% \ExtractKthArg{<integer K>}%
%%               {<tokens in case list of undelimited args doesn't have a k-th argumnent>}%
%%               {<list of undelimited args>} %
%% 
%% In case there is no K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver <tokens in case list of undelimited args doesn't have a k-th argumnent.
%% In case there is a K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver that K-th argument with one level of braces removed.
%%
%% Examples:
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{0}{not available}{ABCDE} yields: not available
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{ABCDE} yields:  C
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{AB{CD}E} yields:  CD
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{4}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}{004}{005}} yields: 004
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{6}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}} yields: not available 
%% 
%% Due to \romannumeral-expansion the result can be obtained by triggering
%% two expansion-steps.
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\ExtractKthArg[2]{%
  \romannumeral%
  % #1: <integer number K>
  % #2: <action if there is no K-th argument>
  \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck[3]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}{% empty
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\begingroup
\def\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop#1{%
  \endgroup
  \@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax{%
    \long\def\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax##1##2#1{{##1}}%
  }%
  \newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop[3]{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo##3{}.}{\UD@stopromannumeral##2}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{##1}{%
        \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{##3#1}%
      }{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}##3}%
        {\expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}##1}{##2}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
\expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
%% Usage of frozen-\relax as delimiter is for speeding things up by reducing the
%% amount of iterations needed. I chose frozen-\relax because David Carlisle 
%% pointed out in   <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578877>
%% that frozen-\relax cannot be (re)defined in terms of \outer and cannot be
%% affected by \uppercase/\lowercase.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg's argument may contain frozen-\relax:
%% The only effect is that internally more iterations are needed for
%% obtaining the result.
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo#1{}}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1}}%
}%
%% End of code for \ExtractKthArg.
%%=============================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UD@GobbleToExclam{\long\def\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@abcdeFork{%
  \long\def\UD@abcdeFork#1!a!b!c!d!e!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\dothis[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
  \ExtractKthArg{%
    %==\ExtractKthArg's 1st argument=<integer K>===============================
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!}{%
      \UD@abcdeFork
      !#1!b!c!d!e!{1}% <- #1 = a: deliver 1st argument
      !a!#1!c!d!e!{2}% <- #1 = b: deliver 2nd argument
      !a!b!#1!d!e!{3}% <- #1 = c: deliver 3rd argument
      !a!b!c!#1!e!{1}% <- #1 = d: deliver 1st argument
      !a!b!c!d!#1!{4}% <- #1 = e: deliver 4th argument
      !a!b!c!d!e!{5}% <- #1 doesn't contain ! and is neither a nor b nor c nor d nor e: deliver 5th argument
      !!!!%
    }{5}% <- #1 does contain ! and thus is neither a nor b nor c nor d nor e: deliver 5th argument
    %==End of \ExtractKthArg's 1st argument====================================
  }{%==\ExtractKthArg's 2nd argument=<tokens in case list of undelimited args
    %   doesn't have a k-th argumnent> It is left empty as a K-th argument is
    %   in the list for each value K that can occur.
  }{%==\ExtractKthArg's 3rd argument=<list of undelimited arguments>===========
    {You typed a or you typed d.}% - 1st argument
    {You typed b.}% - 2nd argument
    {You typed c.}% - 3rd argument
    {You typed e.}% - 4th argument
    {You typed something which is neither a nor b nor c nor d nor e.}% - 5th argument
  }%
}%
%%=============================================================================
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\dothis{a}

\dothis{b}

\dothis{c}

\dothis{d}

\dothis{e}

\dothis{f}

\dothis{!f!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you need to fork many different cases so that a single forking-macro would require a delimiter which is cluttered, you can use more than one forking macro.

E.g., instead of `\UD@abcdeFork` you can combine usage of `\UD@abcFork` and `\UD@deFork`:

```latex
\makeatletter
\errorcontextlines=10000
%%=============================================================================
%% PARAPHERNALIA:
%% \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond,
%% \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull,
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%%
%% Extract K-th inner undelimited argument:
%%
%% \ExtractKthArg{<integer K>}%
%%               {<tokens in case list of undelimited args doesn't have a k-th argumnent>}%
%%               {<list of undelimited args>} %
%% 
%% In case there is no K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver <tokens in case list of undelimited args doesn't have a k-th argumnent.
%% In case there is a K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver that K-th argument with one level of braces removed.
%%
%% Examples:
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{0}{not available}{ABCDE} yields: not available
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{ABCDE} yields:  C
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{not available}{AB{CD}E} yields:  CD
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{4}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}{004}{005}} yields: 004
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{6}{not available}{{001}{002}{003}} yields: not available 
%% 
%% Due to \romannumeral-expansion the result can be obtained by triggering
%% two expansion-steps.
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\ExtractKthArg[2]{%
  \romannumeral%
  % #1: <integer number K>
  % #2: <action if there is no K-th argument>
  \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck[3]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}{% empty
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\begingroup
\def\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop#1{%
  \endgroup
  \@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax{%
    \long\def\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax##1##2#1{{##1}}%
  }%
  \newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop[3]{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo##3{}.}{\UD@stopromannumeral##2}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{##1}{%
        \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{##3#1}%
      }{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}##3}%
        {\expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}##1}{##2}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
\expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
%% Usage of frozen-\relax as delimiter is for speeding things up by reducing the
%% amount of iterations needed. I chose frozen-\relax because David Carlisle 
%% pointed out in   <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578877>
%% that frozen-\relax cannot be (re)defined in terms of \outer and cannot be
%% affected by \uppercase/\lowercase.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg's argument may contain frozen-\relax:
%% The only effect is that internally more iterations are needed for
%% obtaining the result.
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo#1{}}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1}}%
}%
%% End of code for \ExtractKthArg.
%%=============================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UD@GobbleToExclam{\long\def\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@abcFork{%
  \long\def\UD@abcFork#1!a!b!c!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@deFork{%
  \long\def\UD@deFork#1!d!e!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\dothis[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
  \ExtractKthArg{%
    %==\ExtractKthArg's 1st argument=<integer K>===============================
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!}{%
      \UD@abcFork
      !#1!b!c!{1}% <- #1 = a: deliver 1st argument
      !a!#1!c!{2}% <- #1 = b: deliver 2nd argument
      !a!b!#1!{3}% <- #1 = c: deliver 3rd argument
      !a!b!c!{%  <- #1 does not contain ! and is neither a nor b nor c / in this case number is delivered by \UD@deFork
        \UD@deFork
        !#1!e!{1}% <- #1 = d: deliver 1st argument
        !d!#1!{4}% <- #1 = e: deliver 4th argument
        !d!e!{5}% <- #1 (doesn't contain ! and) is neither (a nor b nor c nor) d nor e: deliver 5th argument
        !!!!%
      }%
      !!!!%
    }{5}% <- #1 does contain ! and thus is neither a nor b nor c nor d nor e: deliver 5th argument
    %==End of \ExtractKthArg's 1st argument====================================
  }{%==\ExtractKthArg's 2nd argument=<tokens in case list of undelimited args
    %   doesn't have a k-th argumnent> It is left empty as a K-th argument is
    %   in the list for each value K that can occur.
  }{%==\ExtractKthArg's 3rd argument=<list of undelimited arguments>===========
    {You typed a or you typed d.}% - 1st argument
    {You typed b.}% - 2nd argument
    {You typed c.}% - 3rd argument
    {You typed e.}% - 4th argument
    {You typed something which is neither a nor b nor c nor d nor e.}% - 5th argument
  }%
}%
%%=============================================================================
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\dothis{a}

\dothis{b}

\dothis{c}

\dothis{d}

\dothis{e}

\dothis{f}

\dothis{!f!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, with a recent LaTeX kernel, there's no need to load packages in order to have `expl3`.

Comment: @egreg That's right. I edited my preliminary comment accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In LuaTeX you can use Lua tables to emulate a switch statement.

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\dothis[1]{%
  \directlua{
    local cases = {
        a = "so you typed a",
        b = "now this is b",
        c = "you want to do c?"
    }

    if cases["\luaescapestring{#1}"] \string~= nil then
        tex.sprint(cases["\luaescapestring{#1}"])
    else
        tex.sprint("[nada]")
    end
  }
}

\begin{document}

\dothis{a}

\dothis{b}

\dothis{c}

\dothis{d}

\end{document}
```

[image]