# svg package: inkscape doesn't start

Tags: luatex, windows, svg, inkscape

I use LuaLaTeX (up to date MikTeX +TexStudio)and try to get svg work under Windows.
I studied both
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74693/80573 and
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158612/80573
And followed intructions, tried both the method suggested by Speravir and directly setting the path in package options

```
inkscape= {"C:/Program Files/Inkscape/inkscape.exe" -z -D}
```

I also tried to doctor svg.sty: remove `./` and add quotation marks around input and output files paths.
But I still have a problem that inkscape never starts. I looked in task manager while compiling the document, looking for incscape to appear there  - it never does. Accordingly .pdf and .pdf_tex files are not produced, and the compiler complains about missing files.

```
"C:/ProgramFiles/Inkscape/inkscape.exe"-z-D -f "chapters/images/system_abstract.
svg" -A "chapters/images/system_abstract.pdf" --export-latex

! LaTeX Error: File `chapters/images/system_abstract' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 \includesvg{system_abstract}

I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: File `chapters/images/system_abstract' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 \includesvg{system_abstract}

I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: File `system_abstract.pdf_tex' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: pdf_tex)
```

i noticed the missing space in "Program Files", and tried to force it

```
inkscape= {"C:/Program\space Files/Inkscape/inkscape.exe" -z -D}
```

to no effect: the space character is still missing

In addition, I tried to execute the command from the log file manually in the command processor from the root folder of the document

```
 "C:/ProgramFiles/Inkscape/inkscape.exe"-z-D -f "chapters/images/system_abstract.
    svg" -A "chapters/images/system_abstract.pdf" --export-latex
```

I added spaces to "Programm Files" and beetween the options and change slashes to backslashes

```
"C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" -z -D -f "
chapters\images\system_abstract.svg" -A "chapters\images\system_abstract.pdf" --
export-latex
```

It ran successfully and produced the output files, which in turn allowed the document to compile. That proves that the problem lies with starting of the inkscape or perhaps with how the parameter are transferred to the linkscape binary.

How can i make the svg package to start the linkscape?

Comment: Did you try to un-install Inkscape and re-install it into a directory, whose path does not contain any spaces and try to give `inkscape= {"C:/Program Files/Inkscape/inkscape.exe" -z -D}` with `/`s instead of `/`?