# svg to tex with svg package and inkscape: make the text to wrap inside a shape

Tags: svg, inkscape

I use LuaLaTeX (up to date MikTeX +TexStudio) and wish to use SVG illutsrations in my document, which are created in MS Visio.
here is the original image
[image]

As a quick and dirt fix to [my problem with svg package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325631/svg-package-inkscape-doesnt-start) I launch inkskape manually with batch file in same manner as svg package is supposed to do it

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" -z -D -f %1 -A "%~dpn1.pdf" --export-latex
```

and compile the document.
Here how it looks in the pdf.
[image: result image]

It looks quite good: the shapes are correct, the font adjusted to the font of the document and enlarged where appropriate.
Except it doesn't wrap around to a new line inside the shape.The attempt to force the line break with `\newline` is ignored.
here is the content of pdf_tex file

```
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{497.74924049bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.40658965)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{system_abstract.pdf}}%
    \put(0.41094927,0.3789432){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{\large{Measurement board}}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=2]{system_abstract.pdf}}%
    \put(0.85230537,0.31601965){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{\large{Battery}}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=3]{system_abstract.pdf}}%
    \put(0.06182823,0.21124862){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{{\large Raspberry PI 2}\newline Reads the data and adjusts the current}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=4]{system_abstract.pdf}}%
    \put(0.53429834,0.28286294){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{Current Actuator}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=5]{system_abstract.pdf}}%
    \put(0.35378604,0.2015892){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{SPI}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=6]{system_abstract.pdf}}%
    \put(0.51717328,0.11581522){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{Ammeter+Voltmeter}}}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=7]{system_abstract.pdf}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

Is there a way to fix it? May be with some additional LaTeX code in the image?

Answer (score 1):

You could manually split the text in two lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\unitlength}{497.74924049bp}%
\begin{picture}(1,0.40658965)%
  \put(0.06182823,0.21124862){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{{\large Raspberry PI 2}}}}%
  \put(0.06182823,0.18){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{Reads the data and adjusts the current}}}%
\end{picture}%

\end{document}
```

Or you could wrap the in a `\parbox` of appropriate width to get automatic line breaks:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\unitlength}{497.74924049bp}%
\begin{picture}(1,0.40658965)%
  \put(0.06182823,0.21124862){%
    \parbox{3cm}{%  
        {\large Raspberry PI 2}
        Reads the data and adjusts the current
    }%
  }%
\end{picture}%

\end{document}
```