# Evaluate strings of key-value option in custom package by using a switch-case environment

Tags: packages, conditionals, package-writing, key-value, kvoptions

I'm trying to write a custom package *MyUnicodefonts* where I'd like to store all my font settings for various **math fonts** and **roman fonts** (later also mono and sans).

In my document I intend to choose the font with a key-value option, like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[math=xits,roman=myriad]{MyUnicodefonts}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

For the package file *MyUnicodefonts.sty* I used the switch from [**this answer**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187710/36835) as is appeared handy and sufficient for me and I didn't understood the other answers. I tried to apply it for string comparison.

Using the **kvoptions** package my file finally looks as follows:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{MyUnicodefonts}[2015/06/21 Load fonts]

\RequirePackage{fontspec}

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\DeclareStringOption[minion]{roman}
\DeclareStringOption[xits]{math}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\RequirePackage{xifthen}
\newcommand{\ifequals}[3]{\ifthenelse{\ifstrequal{#1}{#2}{TRUE}{}}{#3}{}}
\newcommand{\case}[2]{#1 #2} % Dummy, so \renewcommand has something to overwrite...
\newenvironment{switch}[1]{\renewcommand{\case}{\ifequals{#1}}}{}

\begin{switch}{\MyUnicodefonts@roman}
    \case{minion}{\setmainfont[Numbers = OldStyle,
                               Ligatures = TeX,
                              ]{Minion Pro}}
    \case{myriad}{\setmainfont[Numbers={Uppercase,OldStyle},
                              ]{Myriad Pro}}
\end{switch}
\begin{switch}{\MyUnicodefonts@math}
    \case{xits}{%
        \RequirePackage{unicode-math}
        \setmathfont{XITS Math}
        \setmathfont[range={"002B,"002D,"003A-"003E} ]{MnSymbol} % + - < = >
        }
    \case{iwona}{%
        \RequirePackage[math]{iwona}
        \RequirePackage[mathscr]{eucal}
        }
\end{switch}

\endinput
```

As the [**kvoptions manual**](ftp://ftp.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/kvoptions.pdf) is lacking a comprehensive example I fail to identify the reason for the appearing *Undefined control sequence error*.

The error would disappear if I'd load `unicode-math` also before the switch, but I don't want that, as there will be cases, where I don't want to use an unicode-math font. However a new error appears:

> ! Missing number, treated as zero.   \begingroup 
>   l.18     \case{myriad}{\setmainfont{Myriad Pro}}
>                                                  A number should have been here; I inserted '0'. (If you can't figure out why I needed to
>   see a number, look up 'weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

Which I don't understand, as I substituted the `\equal{#1}{#2}` from the original switch (see linked answer) to `\ifstrequal{#1}{#2}{TRUE}{}`.

I hope you can help me find the error or suggest a completely different approach.

Comment: The undefined command is shown in the error message: `\ifstrequal`. It is defined by package `etoolbox`, which is not loaded. This and how option strings are processed further are *not* related to package `kvoptions`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code in the question has some problems:

- `\ifstrequal` is not defined, as shown by the error message.
  It is defined by package `etoolbox`.
- Environment `switch` makes a group, all local settings are lost
  after the end of the environment.

There are lots of ways to implement "switches", this is *not* covered by package `kvoptions`, which tries to be simple and easy to use.

A classical way to implement a switch depending on a simple text string is using the hash table of TeX. The following example puts the implementation for an option value in a macro with a name of the form `\<prefix>@<option>@<value>`. The option setting of `kvoptions` stores the value in `\<prefix>@<option>`. Then a simple test using `\@ifundefined` checks, if the option/value implementation exists and throws an error, if the option value is not supported/unknown.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{MyUnicodefonts}[2015/06/21 Load fonts]

\RequirePackage{fontspec}

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\DeclareStringOption[minion]{roman}
\DeclareStringOption[xits]{math}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

% Implementations for option "roman"
\@namedef{MyUnicodefonts@roman@minion}{%
  \setmainfont[
    Numbers = OldStyle,
    Ligatures = TeX,
  ]{Minion Pro}%
}
\@namedef{MyUnicodefonts@roman@myriad}{%
  \setmainfont[
    Numbers={Uppercase,OldStyle},
  ]{Myriad Pro}%
}

% Implementations for option "math"
\@namedef{MyUnicodefonts@math@xits}{%
  \RequirePackage{unicode-math}%
  \setmathfont{XITS Math}%
  \setmathfont[range={"002B,"002D,"003A-"003E}]{MnSymbol}%
}
\@namedef{MyUnicodefonts@math@iwona}{%
  \RequirePackage[math]{iwona}%
  \RequirePakcage[mathscr]{eucal}%
}

% Evaluate option settings
\newcommand*{\MyUnicodefonts@evaluate}[1]{%
  % Check, if option value in \<prefix>@<option> exists
  \@ifundefined{MyUnicodefonts@#1}{%
    % Should not happen
    \PackageError{MyUnicodefonts}{Evaluating unknown option `#1'}\@ehc
  }{%
    % Check, if there is an implementation for the value of the option
    % in macro \<prefix>@<option>@<value>
    \@ifundefined{MyUnicodefonts@#1@\csname MyUnicodefonts@#1\endcsname}{%
      \PackageError{MyUnicodefonts}{%
        Unknown option setting: #1=%
        \csname MyUnicodefonts@#1\endcsname
      }\@ehc
    }{%
      % Call the implementation for the value
      \csname MyUnicodefonts@#1@%
              \csname MyUnicodefonts@#1\endcsname
      \endcsname
      \relax
    }%
  }%
}
\MyUnicodefonts@evaluate{roman}
\MyUnicodefonts@evaluate{math}

\endinput
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `l3keys2e`.

### File `myunicodefonts.sty`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{myunicodefonts}[2015/06/21 Load fonts]

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \g_myunicodefonts_mathfont_bool
\tl_new:N \g_myunicodefonts_textfont_tl
\tl_new:N \g_myunicodefonts_mathfont_tl

\keys_define:nn { myunicodefonts }
 {
  textfont .choice:,
  textfont/minion .code:n = \tl_gset:Nn \g_myunicodefonts_textfont_tl {Minion~Pro},
  textfont/myriad .code:n = \tl_gset:Nn \g_myunicodefonts_textfont_tl {Myriad~Pro},
  textfont .initial:n = minion,
  textoptions .tl_gset:N = \g_myunicodefonts_textfont_options_tl,
  mathfont .choice:,
  mathfont/xits .code:n =
   {
    \bool_gset_true:N \g_myunicodefonts_mathfont_bool
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_myunicodefonts_mathfont_tl {XITS~Math}
   },
  mathfont/asana .code:n =
   { 
    \bool_gset_true:N \g_myunicodefonts_mathfont_bool
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_myunicodefonts_mathfont_tl {Asana~Math}
   },
  mathoptions .tl_gset:N = \g_myunicodefonts_mathfont_options_tl,
 }


\ProcessKeysPackageOptions{myunicodefonts}

\use:x
 {
  \setmainfont{\g_myunicodefonts_textfont_tl}[\g_myunicodefonts_textfont_options_tl]
 }

\bool_if:NT \g_myunicodefonts_mathfont_bool
 {
  \RequirePackage{unicode-math}
  \use:x
   {
    \setmathfont[\g_myunicodefonts_mathfont_options_tl]{\g_myunicodefonts_mathfont_tl}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\endinput
```

### File `myunicodefonts.tex` for testing

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  mathfont=xits,
  textfont=myriad,
  textoptions={Scale=0.8},
]{myunicodefonts}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

One can supplement this with error checking for wrong options.

### Different code

If you want to set yourself the options for the fonts, just do so in the `.case:n` code.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{MyUnicodefonts}[2015/06/21 Load fonts]

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { myunicodefonts }
 {
  textfont .choice:,
  textfont/minion .code:n =
   {
    \setmainfont{Minion~Pro}[
      Numbers = OldStyle,
      Ligatures = TeX,
    ]
   },
  textfont/myriad .code:n =
   {
    \setmainfont{Myriad~Pro}[
      Numbers={Uppercase,OldStyle},
    ]
   },
  textfont .initial:n = minion,
  mathfont .choice:,
  mathfont/xits .code:n =
   {
    \RequirePackage{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{XITS~Math}
    \setmathfont[range={"002B,"002D,"003A-"003E}]{MnSymbol} % + - < = >
   },
  mathfont/iwona .code:n =
   { 
    \RequirePackage[math]{iwona}
    \RequirePackage[mathscr]{eucal}
   },
 }

\ProcessKeysPackageOptions{myunicodefonts}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\endinput
```

Comment: Thank you for this exhausting piece of code, but I'm a little struggling to apply it to the full case. First it seems I'm limited to the options I could define within the `[]` in `\setmathfont[<options>]{font}` - is that right? But I actually have multiple of these lines for different ranges. Also the options for the roman fonts should be defined within the class and not be editable from outside. Could you please have a look at my edited MWE and insert it in you code? That would help me to understand where all the definitions reappears. Thank you!

Comment: @thewaywewalk That's a good reason for not having such a package in the first place.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Remove the `textoptions` key and set the token list variable yourself. Similarly add the code you want to the `mathfont` options.

Comment: possibly. It seemed to be a easy thing to do for me in the first place. I will work through your code again tomorrow.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I added an example of what I meant.

Comment: Your second suggestion is much more understandable and exactly what I was looking for!