# Verify that option was set

Tags: packages, package-writing, package-options, kvoptions

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249102/125382) I'm able to verify that an option was set to specific values. But how do I verify that an option was set in case the actual value doesn't matter. I.e. how do I make sure an option is actually set to some value?

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2017/02/14 v1.0 My test class]
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{
    family=TEST,
    prefix=TEST@
}
\DeclareStringOption{testoption}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
% ... how do I verify that testoption was set?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\DeclareStringOption` uses the empty string as initial value for the option value as default. The following example sets the initial value to `\relax`, thus that this can be checked after the option processing:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2017/02/14 v1.0 My test class]
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{
    family=TEST,
    prefix=TEST@
}
\DeclareStringOption{testoption}
% Override initial value for option `testoption`
\let\TEST@testoption\relax
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\ifx\TEST@testoption\relax
  \ClassWarning{testclass}{Option `testoption' is not set.}
\else
  \typeout{Option `testoption' is set to `\TEST@testoption'.}
\fi
```