# Calling macro from a macro breaks argument formatting causes odd environment behavior

Tags: math-mode, macros, arguments

I'm trying to write a little Latex package to learn more about Tex and to help me out with writing long and annoying proofs for a course by creating macros to retrieve rule names from a table given the rules number (which is given in a arbitrary compendium).

But I'm having severe problems with calling macros from within a macro.

This is my code:

```
%macro for formatting rules
\newcommand{\nR}[1]{%
=\;\{\text{{#1}}\}%
}

%Prints the rule specified by the argument from the nametable in a nice formatting
\newcommand{\Rnl}[1]{%
    &\\&\nR{\nT{{#1}}}\\&%
}
%rule nametable
\newcommand{\nT}[1]{%
    \stringcases
    {#1}%
    {%
      {1.1}{Axiom of whatever}%
      {2.1}{Silly theorem}%
    }%
    {\mathbf{UNDEFINED\_RULE\;\;{#1}}}% 
}

%I got these from:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64131/implementing-switch-                            cases
\newcommand{\stringcases}[3]{%
  \romannumeral
    \str@case{#1}#2{#1}{#3}\q@stop
}
\newcommand{\str@case}[3]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\unexpanded{#1}}{\unexpanded{#2}}=\z@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
    {\str@case@end{#3}}
    {\str@case{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\str@case@end}{}
\long\def\str@case@end#1#2\q@stop{\z@#1}
```

But the problem is that when I call from a math environment `\Rnl{1.1}` I get a `\mathbf allowed only in math mode.` although if I change `\mathbf`
to `\textbf` it will output `{UNDEFINED_RULE 1.1}`. Which it shouldn't do since there is a case matching `1.1`.

The really confusing thing is that if i just call `\nT{1.1}` it will output "axiom of whatever" so that macro works as long as I don't call it from within another macro.

Below follows a compilable example of how I aim to use it:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{amsmath}

%%Insert macros from above here.

\begin{document} 

What I want want to be able to write:  
\begin{align*}
   & A \wedge B \Rnl{1.1} Bob \Rnl{2.1} T               
\end{align*}
 What I want to get:
\begin{align*}
   &A \wedge B \\
   &=\;\text{\{The rule that coresponds to 1.1 in the name table\}} \\
   &Bob\\
   &=\;\text{\{The rule that coresponds to 2.1 in the name table\}} \\
   &T               
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please, make a full compilable example.

Comment: Thanks @egreg That solved that issue! But I got a weird undefined control sequence but I'll look into that on my own.

What is the difference between `\DeclareRobustCommand` and `\newcommand` ??

Comment: @HenrikSommerland: If you think egreg's answer solves your troubles please consider to accept it. I can't see the relation to `\DeclareRobustCommand` here however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see too many braces and `\;` in your code; the latter have no real consequences apart bad spacing, the additional braces are the key in understanding what goes wrong.

You have `\Rnl{1.1}` in your code, that, according to the definition, becomes

```
&\\&\nR{\nT{{1.1}}}\\&
```

The main part is, of course, `\nR{\nT{{1.1}}}` that becomes

```
=\;\{\text{{\nT{{1.1}}}}\}
```

and now `\nT{{1.1}}` becomes

```
\stringcases
  {{1.1}}%
  {%
    {1.1}{Axiom of whatever}%
    {2.1}{Silly theorem}%
  }%
  {\mathbf{UNDEFINED\_RULE\;\;{{1.1}}}}%
```

(I kept the line breaks just for clarity). Can you see the problem? The token list to be tested against the cases is `{1.1}` that *does not* appear in the possible choices.

The error about `\mathbf` is because this is in `\text` where `\mathbf` is of course illegal.

Remove the additional braces and you'll be OK:

```
%macro for formatting rules
\newcommand{\nR}[1]{%
  =\{\text{#1}\}%
}

%Prints the rule specified by the argument from the nametable in a nice formatting
\newcommand{\Rnl}[1]{%
  \\
  &\nR{\nT{#1}}\\
  &
}
%rule nametable
\newcommand{\nT}[1]{%
  \stringcases{#1}%
    {%
      {1.1}{Axiom of whatever}%
      {2.1}{Silly theorem}%
    }%
    {\textbf{UNDEFINED\_RULE #1}}%
}
```