# switch-case condition

Tags: conditionals

There are only two clause in `\ifthenelse`—<then clause> and <clause>. If more than two test conditions are needed, the `\ifthenelse` has to be nested. This will make code awful and be hard to maintain.
Is there a better way, for example, switch-case marco like this(like C language):

```
\switchconditon
  {<case 1> <clause 1>}
  {<case 2> <clause 2>}
  {<case 3> <clause 3>}
```

an example by `\ifthenelse`:

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{ul}}%ul=upper left
        {\let\position\AtPageUpperLeft}
        {}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{ll}}%ll=lower left
        {\let\position\AtPageLowerLeft}
        {}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{pc}}%pc=paper center
        {\let\position\AtPageCenter}
        {}
```

Can you give a code to achive the last code function?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Implementing switch cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64131/5764)

Answer (score 12):

The `expl3` programming layer of LaTeX3 comes with a lot of utility functions for such purposes.  The model offers different datastructures and algorithms which operate on them.  Some of them have a `switch` statement, see examples below.

For your use-case the `\str_case:nn` is appropriate.  If no match is found an error is signalled.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\msg_new:nnn
  { switchcase }
  { no-match }
  { There~is~no~entry~`#1'~in~the~switch~statement! }

\NewDocumentCommand \switchcase { m m }
  {
    \str_case:nnF { #1 } { #2 } { \msg_error:nnn { switchcase } { no-match } { #1 } }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\whatever[1]{%
  \switchcase{#1}%
  {
    {ul}{\let\position\AtPageUpperLeft}
    {ll}{\let\position\AtPageLowerLeft}
    {pc}{\let\position\AtPageCenter}
  }%
}

% Sentinel
\newcommand*\AtPageUpperLeft{AtPageUpperLeft}
\newcommand*\AtPageLowerLeft{AtPageLowerLeft}
\newcommand*\AtPageCenter   {AtPageCenter}


\begin{document}

\whatever{ul}\position

\whatever{ll}\position

\whatever{pc}\position

\whatever{rubbish}\position % error!

\end{document}
```

---

For macros you can use `\tl_case:nn`:

[image]

If you want to compare strings in a catcode agnostic fashion, use `\str_case:nn`

[image]

For integers there is `\int_case:nn`

[image]

For dimensions there is `\dim_case:nn`

[image]

Comment: Thank you Menke. The Package expl3 must be declared? And could you show me how to use it through my updated code example.

Comment: It seems a bit complicate. Anyway, many thanks again. I'll try to understand it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a fairly general switch case macro, based on `expl3`. The syntax is

```
\switchcondition[<type>]{<input>}[<other>]{<cases>}
```

where `<type>` is one among `string`, `token`, `integer` or `dimen` (default `string`), `<input>` is the argument to test against the cases, `<other>` is what to do if no case is matched, and `<cases>` is the list of cases in the form

```
{<case-1>}{<code-1>}
{<case-2>}{<code-2>}
[...]
{<case-n>}{<code-n>}
```

The macro is, by itself, fully expandable, but of course this feature can be exploited only if `<other>` and `<code-k>` are fully expandable for every case.

Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\switchcondition}{O{string}mmO{}}
 {
  \use:c { lyl_#1_switch:nnn } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \lyl_string_switch:nnn
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \lyl_token_switch:nnn
 {
  \tl_case:nnF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \lyl_integer_switch:nnn
 {
  \int_case:nnF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \lyl_dimen_switch:nnn
 {
  \dim_case:nnF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\placement}[1]{%
  \switchcondition{#1}{
    {ul}{\let\position\AtPageUpperLeft}
    {ll}{\let\position\AtPageLowerLeft}
    {ur}{\let\position\AtPageUpperRight}
    {lr}{\let\position\AtPageLowerRight}
  }[\let\position\ERROR]%
}

% whatever these should do
\providecommand{\AtPageUpperLeft}{APUL}
\providecommand{\AtPageLowerLeft}{APLL}
\providecommand{\AtPageUpperRight}{APUR}
\providecommand{\AtPageLowerRight}{APLR}
\providecommand{\ERROR}{ERROR}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \switchcondition[integer]{#1}{
    {1}{One}
    {20}{Twenty}
    {42}{The answer!}
  }[Uninteresting number]%
}

\begin{document}

\placement{ul}\texttt{\meaning\position}

\placement{ll}\texttt{\meaning\position}

\placement{ur}\texttt{\meaning\position}

\placement{lr}\texttt{\meaning\position}

\placement{xy}\texttt{\meaning\position}

\foo{1}

\foo{6*7}

\foo{3456}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you egreg. I need to learn more about the package xparse.

Answer (score 5):

You can also just let TeX's csname hash table do the lookup for you so

```
\def\positionul{\let\position\AtPageUpperLeft}
\def\positionll{\let\position\AtPageLowerLeft}
\def\positionpc{\let\position\AtPageCenter}
```

then in the macro that you did not show, that wants to use `#1` being `ul`, `ll` or `pc` just use

```
\csname position#1\endcsname
```

and it will execute `\positionll` if `#1` is `ll`

Comment: I think this is a good and simple solution. By the way, why the following code does not show "aaa"?
\def\t1{aaa}
\def\t2{bbb}
\newcommand{\tttt}[1]{\csname t#1\endcsname}
\tttt{1}

Comment: `\def\t1{aaa}` defines `\t` followed by `1` you would need `\expandafter\def\csname t1\endcsname{aaa}` to access a macro named t1

Comment: Thank you. I want to define a marco named "\t1" by input "expandafter\def\csname t1\endcsname{aaa}", then I want to get "aaa" by input \t1,but "aaa" did not show. why?

Comment: @lyl same reason `\t1` is the same as `\t  1`  the two tokens `\t` and `1` to access a command with name `t1` you would need `\csname t1\endcsname`