# Problem with expansion in xparse

Tags: expansion, expl3, xparse

I am trying to use function from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386307/100689)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\switchcondition}{ O{string} m m m }
     {
      \use:c { fraiman_#1_switch:nnn } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
     }

    \cs_new:Nn \fraiman_string_switch:nnn
     {
      \str_case:nnF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
     }
    \cs_new:Nn \fraiman_token_switch:nnn
     {
      \tl_case:nnF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
     }
    \cs_new:Nn \fraiman_integer_switch:nnn
     {
      \int_case:nnF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
     }
    \cs_new:Nn \fraiman_dimen_switch:nnn
     {
      \dim_case:nnF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
     }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

    \newcommand{\Hello}{A4}

    \switchcondition{\Hello}{
        {A4}{It is A4}
        {A5}{It is A5}
    }{Oops!}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that I always get "Oops!", no matter how I define `\Hello`.

However,

```
    \switchcondition{A5}{
        {A4}{It is A4}
        {A5}{It is A5}
    }{Oops!}
```

works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the first argument of `\str_case:nnF` to be fully expanded, you have to use `\str_case_e:nnF` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\switchcondition}{ O{string} m m m }
     {
      \use:c { fraiman_#1_switch:nnn } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
     }

    \cs_new:Nn \fraiman_string_switch:nnn
     {
      \str_case_e:nnF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
     }
    \cs_new:Nn \fraiman_token_switch:nnn
     {
      \tl_case:nnF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
     }
    \cs_new:Nn \fraiman_integer_switch:nnn
     {
      \int_case:nnF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
     }
    \cs_new:Nn \fraiman_dimen_switch:nnn
     {
      \dim_case:nnF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
     }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

    \newcommand{\Hello}{A4}

    \switchcondition{\Hello}{
        {A4}{It is A4}
        {A5}{It is A5}
    }{Oops!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\str_case_e:nnF` also fully expands some of the token lists inside the second argument (`A4` and `A5` in the OP's example: these two are unchanged by this process unless catcodes have been severely tampered with). If expansion of only the first argument is desired, one can use variants such as `\str_case:onF` (exactly **o**ne expansion step) or `\str_case:xnF` (full expansion). This is a complement, not a criticism of the answer. :-)

Comment: Well, I must add that `\str_case:xnF` won't work correctly in this context (called from a macro defined with `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`). `\str_case:enF` should, but requires a relatively recent TeX engine, otherwise it will be very slow. But `\str_case:onF` is always an option, if one expansion step is enough.