# Is there a gentle introduction to learning expl3 syntax

Tags: latex3, expl3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programming with LaTeX3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84605/programming-with-latex3)

I was going to post a question about creating a switch within a command to determine formatting for a command and came across the following link
[String test, with complicated arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43601/string-test-with-complicated-arguments) in which I discovered the `expl3` equivalents of `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`.  So I tried to make my command as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mytestcmd}{ O{a} m}
    {
        \prg_case_str:nnn { #1 }
        {
            { a } { A }
            { b } { B }
            { c } { CC }
            { d } { DED }
        }
        :#2
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\mytestcmd{Hello}

\mytestcmd[b]{Hello}

\mytestcmd[c]{Hello}

\mytestcmd[d]{Hello}

\end{document}
```

But then I got the unexpected result that my colon from `:#2` was not showing up in the actual rendered text.  I'm sure there's a simple solution for this.  I'm not actually so interested in someone telling me how to fix is particular issue with the colon.

However, I do find the *expl3* documentation quite daunting.  Is there an **expl3 primer** or some kind of **expl3 for dummies** around where I can learn some thing without feeling like I'm drowning?

Incidentally, normally I would handle the switch as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\def\my@test@cmd@a{a}
\def\my@test@cmd@b{b}
\def\my@test@cmd@c{c}
\def\my@test@cmd@d{d}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mytestcmd}{ O{a} m}
    {%
        \def\my@test@cmd{#1}%
        \ifx\my@test@cmd\my@test@cmd@a{A}\fi%
        \ifx\my@test@cmd\my@test@cmd@b{B}\fi%
        \ifx\my@test@cmd\my@test@cmd@c{C}\fi%
        \ifx\my@test@cmd\my@test@cmd@d{D}\fi%
        :#2%
    }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\mytestcmd{Hello}

\mytestcmd[b]{Hello}

\mytestcmd[c]{Hello}

\mytestcmd[d]{Hello}

\end{document}
```

What I like about the `expl3` syntax is it seems to be much kinder in building a true switch than my work around.

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84605/programming-with-latex3

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  No.  I hadn't see that.  Hmmm.  Should I remove my question as the duplicate?  Or should it be flagged as a duplicate to help someone else find that link?  I sadly did not think to search on `latex3`

Comment: BTW, you can `\IfEqCase` from [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/) can be used to case type statements. See for example [Making switch/case with etoolbox's \ifdefequal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5116/making-switch-case-with-etoolboxs-ifdefequal/53501#53501).  BTW, I'd recommend you _not_ delete the question as others may come across this in their search and then will can follow the duplicate link.

Comment: @A.Ellett Two points about your specific case. First, `\prg_case_str:nnn` got renamed as `\str_case:nnn` a while ago. Second, this function requires _three_ arguments (`nnn`) and you've only given two. So the `:` is taken as the third one, which is why it vanishes. You need an empty argument (`{ }`) after the end of the cases.

Comment: @JosephWright, Trying to follow your suggestions, I only just updated my LiveTex version last week, yet neverthess when I run tex on `\str_case:nnn` it complains about an *undefined control sequence*.  Despite this, I appreciate your help

Comment: @A.Ellett That will depend on what you mean by 'updated your TeX Live'. The TL2012 DVD version was frozen in July 2012, and we deliberately did not make this change until just after that. So if you have the DVD version the old name will still stand.

Comment: @JosephWright.  I downloaded TL2012 from what's posted on the mactex website:  though that may just be the same thing that is on the DVD.  After downloading it, I ran `tlmgr update --self`.

Comment: @A.Ellett `tlmgr update --self` updates `tlmgr` itself, but not anything installed. You'd need `tlmgr update --self --all` to update your packages.