# Randomizing font family throughout a document

Tags: latex3

Is there a way to randomize font family throughout a document? 
The reason behind doing this is to help pay more attention when reviewing a document. Mainly because we tend to pay more attention to the text if fonts randomly and often change throughout a document.

Comment: We tend to pay more attention to the fonts. We tend to pay less attention to the content. Good typography is not noticed precisely because it does not distract readers from the content.

Comment: @cfr I think the OP will only use this magic for his personal proof reading and not for anybody else, if that's what you mean :).

Answer (score 1):

How's that for a start? I am sure that the experts here can make it more flexible and more automatic.

The `\marginpar` stuff is just to demonstrate/debug the random numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5116
% \IfEqCase
\usepackage{xstring}

% \pgfmathparse and \pgfmathresult
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\myRandomFontCommand}[1]{%
    \IfEqCase*{#1}{%
    {1}{\normalfont\bfseries}%
    {2}{\normalfont\rmfamily}%
    {3}{\normalfont\ttfamily}%
    {4}{\normalfont\itshape}%
    {5}{\normalfont\scshape}%
    }[]%
}%

% Inspiration
%\rmfamily
%\sffamily 
%\ttfamily
%\mdseries
%\bfseries
%\itshape
%\scshape

% \blindtext
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathparse{random(1,5)}
\myRandomFontCommand{\pgfmathresult}
\marginpar{\protect\pgfmathresult}

\blindtext

\pgfmathparse{random(1,5)}
\myRandomFontCommand{\pgfmathresult}
\marginpar{\protect\pgfmathresult}

\blindtext

\pgfmathparse{random(1,5)}
\myRandomFontCommand{\pgfmathresult}
\marginpar{\protect\pgfmathresult}

\blindtext

\pgfmathparse{random(1,5)}
\myRandomFontCommand{\pgfmathresult}
\marginpar{\protect\pgfmathresult}

\blindtext

\pgfmathparse{random(1,5)}
\myRandomFontCommand{\pgfmathresult}
\marginpar{\protect\pgfmathresult}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

### Alternative (a more automatic approach)

```
%% (same preamble)

\begin{document}

\everypar={
\pgfmathparse{random(1,5)}
\myRandomFontCommand{\pgfmathresult}
\marginpar{\protect\pgfmathresult}
}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

But I do really not know if `everypar` is a good choice...

Comment: This is a great start! Is there a way that each word instead of paragraph could be randomized?

Comment: @ZanCoul That's out of my league, sorry. I would guess that it is not easy and maybe to much effort considering the benefits (just an opinion). In addition, it's likely that there may be some side effects (interaction with other commands and so on) that cause trouble. I would go for another approach and would try too **improve your prove reading skills/methods :).**

Comment: I hesitate to encourage this, but `cfr-lm` would provide more options than `lmodern` does. However, I utterly deplore the whole idea. I think it is nuts.

Comment: @cfr You could at least like the solution and upvote it :).

Comment: @cfr  Just read the documentation of your lm package, very cool.